# Is there an additive functor between abelian categories which isn't exact in the middle?

Tags: ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, homological-algebra, examples

Suppose $F: C\to D$ is an additive functor between abelian categories and that

$$0\to X\xrightarrow f Y\xrightarrow g Z\to 0$$

is and exact sequence in $C$. Does it follow that $F(X)\xrightarrow{F(f)} F(Y)\xrightarrow{F(g)} F(Z)$ is exact in $D$? In other words, is $\ker(F(g))=\mathrm{im}(F(f))$?

**Remark 1:** If the answer is no, a counterexample must use a *non-split* short exact sequence. This is because additive functors send split exact sequences to split exact sequences. A splitting is a pair $s:Y\to X$ and $r:Z\to Y$ so that $id_Y=f\circ s+r\circ g$, $id_X=s\circ f$, and $id_Z=g\circ r$. An additive functor preserves these properties, so $F(s)$ and $F(r)$ will split the sequence in $D$.

**Remark 2:** You probably know you know lots of left exact and right exact additive functors, but you also know lots of *exact in the middle* additive functors. $H^i$ and $H_i$ for any (co)homology theory are neither left or right exact, but they are exact in the middle by the long exact sequence in (co)homology.

Comment: Dear Anton,  As was noted in Buschi Sergios comment below my answer, there is a typo in the question.  (You should replace "coker($F(f)$)"
by "im($F(f)$)".)



Comment: @Emerton: Fixed. Thank you. I was so confused when I read that comment since it seemed inconceivable to me that anybody got the exactness condition wrong. How embarrassing!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Consider the abelian category of morphisms of vector spaces, i.e., the objects are linear maps $f:U\to V$, and the morphisms are commutative squares.  Let the functor $Im$ assign to a morphism $f$ its image $Im(f)$.  Consider the short exact sequence of morphisms $(0\to V)\to (U\to V)\to (U\to 0)$.  The functor $Im$ transforms it to the sequence $0\to Im(f)\to 0$, i.e. $Im$ is not exact in the middle.

On the other hand, notice that $Im$ is epimorphic and monomorphic, i.e., transforms epimorphisms to epimorphisms and monomorphisms to monomorphisms.

Comment: This is a very elegant example. Thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the category of morphisms of vector spaces really wants to a 2-category, and this is '2-abelian', see M. Dupont's thesis, http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1760 

Comment: An example which is similar in spirit: Let $F: Ab \to Ab$ be the functor $A \mapsto pA$ for a prime $p$. This functor preserves monomorphisms and epimorphisms, but it is not middle-exact.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391687/284272) for a generalisation: the image of a natural transformation $\eta \colon F \to G$ between exact functors $F, G \colon \mathscr A \to \mathscr B$ is exact in the middle if and only if its kernel is right exact (or its cokernel is left exact).

Answer (score 20):

Composing two random "exact-in-the-middle" functors should give a counterexample.

E.g. let's consider the functor from $\mathbb Z$-modules to itself given by
$$ M \mapsto Hom(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z, M/p^2 M),$$ for some fixed prime $p$.
Applying this to the short exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathbb Z/p^2 \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/p^3\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \to 0$$
(the first non-trivial arrow being mult. by $p$ and the second being the natural projection)
gives the sequence
$$ \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z,$$
with all the arrows being 0 (assuming I haven't miscalculated).

Comment: I think the condition is: $Ker(Fg)= Im(Ff)$ and no $Ker(Fg)= Cok(Ff)$ .

Comment: Yes, this is right.

Comment: Dear Anton, You're welcome.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I remember, there is an important example of a functor that transforms mono- and epimorphisms into  mono- and epimorphisms, respectively, but is not half-exact; this is the functor of intermediate extension of perverse sheaves.

Comment: For an explication of this example, you could look at Ex. 2.7.1 of the survey http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01260-9/

Comment: Yes ... and the relation to Leonid's example is provided by MacPherson and Vilonen's "elementary construction of perverse sheaves", which shows that intermediate extension can be calculated at each step in the stratification by taking an image of a map of vector spaces. So in some sense these are the same example!